# Automaticaly selection (particular area) in the JPG files

Tags: pdf, images, selection, capture

I have some 5000 pages of document (JPG or PDF), each page has around 30 rectangular boxes (some content is there inside the box), I need to capture 30 rectangular boxes automatically and assign some name to it.

Thanks in advance.

Bhaskar

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often are dependent on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's win/mac: I highly recommend using http://puush.me/ It installs a piece of software on your computer and you simply press Ctrl Shift 4, it will create a mouse PLUS LOGO and you can highlight the area you want to take a screen shot of or screen capture.

It will then send that selection to there database and send you back a direct link to the image, then you just save the jpg on your computer.

It also automatically puts that link to your (Ctrl+V) spot for faster use. Puush also keeps a record of all the screenshots you've taken under "My Account" with a 200MB limit

Hope that helps, good luck

And obviously the normal way for windows is to press Prt Scr Button on your keyboard, it will take a screenshot of the entire screen, then you open up paint, Paste the results of the screenshot, and then you can edit whatever you want and save, but in your situation, i don't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Use The GNU Image Manipulation Program, it offers several selection tools that can automate your task. Considering the volume of the data, doing this manually would be rather painful. I'd Look into scripting something with Imagemagic.

GIMP selection tools: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools-selection.html